# Create list view using REST API

Tags: list-view, sharepoint-rest-api

Following method works properly to create list view but I am not able to(don't know) add/select columns in that view, in the same REST API call.

Please Help.

```
$.ajax
({url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('List Name')/views",
type: "POST",
data: "{'__metadata':{'type': 'SP.View'},'ViewType': 'HTML','Title':'view name','PersonalView':false}",            
            headers:
            {
        "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose", 
            "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose", 
                "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
            },
            success: function (data, status, xhr) {               
                  console.log("Success");
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                console.log("Failed");
            }        
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In the body/data you have to pass CAML Query like given below on which your view will be created.

```
"{ '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.View' }, 'Title': 'View Name', 'PersonalView':   true, 'ViewQuery':'" + query + "'  }";
```

**Reference**:

[Create List View using SharePoint REST API](http://blog.techperspect.com/2015/07/create-list-view-using-sharepoint-rest.html).

Comment: ViewQuery is used to filter the view. I want to specify the set of columns for the view.

Answer (score 0):

you can use addviewfiled in the API URI 
much like : _api/web/lists(guid)/views(guid)/viewfields/addviewfield('Title')

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the [SP.ViewCollection.add](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-visio/jj247067(v=office.15)) method. Here's some sample code.

```
<div>
  <button type="button" onclick="buttonClickHandler()">Create View</button>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function buttonClickHandler() {
    var url = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl +
      "/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('Products')/Views/Add";

    var data = {
      "parameters": {
        "__metadata": { type: "SP.ViewCreationInformation" },
        "Title": "New View",
        "ViewFields": {
          "__metadata": {
            "type": "Collection(Edm.String)"
          },
          "results": [
            "LinkTitle",
            "UnitPrice"
          ]
        },
        "Query": "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='ID' /></OrderBy>"
      }
    };

    var call = jQuery.ajax({
      url: url,
      type: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "X-RequestDigest": jQuery("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
      },
      data: JSON.stringify(data),
    });
  }
</script>
```